# Exclude rows from select if that row having more than 1 same value / duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How to just select without a row if that row have duplicates

```
ID | Amount | Status | FK
---+--------+--------+---
1  | -1000  |    T   | 10
2  | -1500  |    T   | 11
3  | -100   |    T   | 12
4  | -200   |    T   | 13
5  | -300   |    T   | 14
6  |  300   |    R   | 14
```

Status explanation: T = Transaction, R = Refund

And how can I just get data with id 1,2,3,4 and exclude 5 and 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option is to use WITH TIES in concert with a window functions

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By sum(1) over (partition by FK)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Amount  Status  FK
1   -1000   T       10
2   -1500   T       11
3   -100    T       12
4   -200    T       13
```

Comment: this is helpfull thank you, but can i ask you question, is WITH TIES is better than
"select * from table_name
where fk not in
(select fk from table_name group by fk having count(1) > 1);" as mentioned by @Jim Maculay ? thank you

Comment: @aldesrahim Always happy to help

Comment: @aldesrahim window functions tend to be rather performant.   That said, only a real world test on your system can prove what the best approach is.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select * from table_name
where fk not in
(select fk from table_name group by fk having count(1) > 1);
```